# Nested Try Catch in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a nested tryCatch in R. The code is following:

```
tryCatch({
    a <- 2/'a'
    print(a)
    print("himanshu")

    tryCatch({
        a <- 3/'a'
        print(a)
        print("inner loop") 

    }, warning = function(war) {
        print("Warning in inner tryCAtch")

    },  error = function(err) {
        print("Error in inner tryCAtch")
    })

 }, warning = function(war) {
        print("Warning in outer tryCAtch")

 }, error = function(err) {
    print("Error in outer tryCAtch")

 })
```

Even if there is an error in inner block the message of outer block are getting printed. I want the output like:

```
Error in inner block
Error in outer block
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you have two problems, the first is that tryCatch() stops executing the try-block when an error occurs, so the second tryCatch() never executes.  The second problem is that you seem to be mixing purposes of a try/catch.

In general, I use tryCatch() in one of three scenarios (1) recovering from a failure, (2) closing opened resources, and (3) passing the error with a better error message.

If you're trying to recover from a failure, it's best
to include just one statement in your try block, otherwise your error handler has to have logic to identify *which* statement failed, which can get ugly fast.

```
tryCatch({
    a_statement_that_might_fail()

},error = function(err){
    recover from failure here

})
```

If you need just need better error messages or to close an open resource, a multi-statement try-block is fine:

```
resource  <-  open_file_or_database()
tryCatch({
    lots()
    of()
    statements()
    that()
    might()
    fail()

},error = function(err){
    stop(sprintf('Got this error: %s',err$message)) 

},finally={
    close(resource)

})
```

Comment: Or you might add `finally` to the `tryCatch` and close all connections in this statement.

Comment: Good point.  I tend not to use `finally` it since it's the odd man out syntactically: the `warning` and `error` handlers take functions and `finally` takes an expression, which throws me off, and it's rare (but not impossible) for a statement in the try-block to stop execution through anything other than an error.

Comment: Any recommendation if you have two statements that cannot mutually succeed? 
In other words, is tryCatch a good function to use as a generalized switch statement/ if/else?

Comment: @Atticus29, Two approaches come to mind. First, you can nest a try-catch in your error handler, but that is syntactically ugly. Alternatively you can set a flag (i.e.  `success = FALSE` prior to a `tryCatch()` call where you call your first method, and as the last statement of the try block, call `success = TRUE`, then test call `if(!success)tryCatch(method2(),...)`.  Another idiom is to have a list of functions `LL=list(function(){do();something();},...)`and use `for(i in seq_along(LL)) try({LL[[i]](); break;})`, which will try each function in `LL` til one executes without error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the error is not causing a both try blocks to halt? That would cause the behaviour you describe.

I was not able to reproduce the problem, so here is a positive example to work from:

```
## Example of nested tryCatch

# set this variable to 'outer_error', 'outer_warning', 'inner_error', 'inner_warning' or empty ('') to see the different scenarios
case <- "inner_error"

result <- "init value"

tryCatch({

  if( case == "outer_error") {
    stop( simpleError("Whoops: outer error") )
  }

  if( case == "outer_warning") {
    stop( simpleWarning("Whoops: outer warning") )
  }

  result <- "first result"

  tryCatch({
    if( case == "inner_error") {
      stop( simpleError("Whoops: inner error") )
    }

    if( case == "inner_warning") {
      stop( simpleWarning("Whoops: inner warning") )
    }

    result <- "Second result!"
  },
  error = function(e) {
    print(sprintf("Inner error: %s", e)) 
  },
  warning = function(e) {
    print(sprintf("Inner warning: %s", e))
  },
  finally = {
    print(sprintf("Inner tryCatch all done, result is %s", result))
  })
},
warning = function (e) {
  print(sprintf("Outer Warning: %s", e) )
},
error = function(e) {
  print(sprintf("Outer Error: %s", e))
},
finally = {
  print(sprintf("And the result is: %s", result))
})
```